# Render different child components in React based on state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a short quiz in React, with each question as a different component. Each time a question is answered, I want to switch that component out for the next question component. Here's my root component as it is right now:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import PanelOne from './components/PanelOne';
import PanelTwo from './components/PanelTwo';
import PanelThree from './components/PanelThree';
import PanelFour from './components/PanelFour';
import Results from './components/Results';

class App extends Component {

  constructor (props) {
    super (props);
    this.state = {
      collaborator: 0,
      pilot: 0,
      producer: 0,
      harmonizer: 0,
      counter: 0
      answers: {
        answersOne: [
          {answer: 'Team building', archetype: 'collaborator'},
          {answer: 'Directing strategy', archetype: 'pilot'},
          {answer: 'Driving task completion', archetype: 'producer'},
          {answer: 'Keeping processes and relationships running smoothly', archetype: 'harmonizer'}
        ],

        answersTwo: [
          {answer: 'Setting a clear direction and creating a personal brand', archetype: 'collaborator'}
          {answer: 'Making space for others and planning for the longterm', archetype: 'pilot'}
          {answer: 'Connecting with team members and innovating', archetype: 'producer'}
          {answer: 'Accepting ambiguity and addressing conflict', archetype: 'harmonizer'}
        ],

        answersThree: [
          {answer: 'Settings where team members are seeking coaching and development', archetype: 'collaborator'}
          {answer: 'Ambiguous and high growth environments', archetype  'pilot'}
          {answer: 'Organizations with clear structures and processes', archetype: 'producer'}
          {answer: 'Volatile settings that need to be tamed'  archetype: 'harmonizer'}
        ],

        answersFour: [
          {answer: 'Settings where unilateral decision making is required', archetype: 'collaborator'}
          {answer: 'Conservative environments that discourage  innovation', archetype: 'pilot'}
          {answer: 'Teams where each member desires independence'  archetype: 'producer'}
          {answer: 'Anywhere tough feedback needs to be given'  archetype: 'harmonizer'}
        ]
      }
    }
    this.onSelect = this.onSelect.bind(this);
  }

  onSelect(value) {
    switch (value) {
      case 'collaborator':
        this.setState(prevState => {
          return {
            collaborator: prevState.collaborator + 1,
            counter: prevState.counter + 1
          }
        });
        break;
      case 'pilot':
        this.setState(prevState => {
          return {
            pilot: prevState.pilot + 1,
            counter: prevState.counter + 1
          }
        });
        break;
      case 'producer':
        this.setState(prevState => {
          return {
            producer: prevState.producer + 1,
            counter: prevState.counter + 1
          }
        });
        break;
      case 'harmonizer':
        this.setState(prevState => {
          return {
            harmonizer: prevState.harmonizer + 1,
            counter: prevState.counter + 1
          }
        });
        break;
    }
  }

  render() {
    switch (this.state.counter) {
      case 0:
        return (
          <div>
            <PanelOne answers={this.state.answers.answersOne} onSelect={this.onSelect}/>
          </div>
        );
        break;
      case 1:
        return (
          <div>
            <PanelTwo answers={this.state.answers.answersTwo} onSelect={this.onSelect}/>
          </div>
        );
        break;
      case 2:
        return (
          <div>
            <PanelThree answers={this.state.answers.answersThree}  onSelect={this.onSelect}/>
          </div>
        );
        break;
      case 3:
        return (
          <div>
            <PanelFour answers={this.state.answers.answersFour}  onSelect={this.onSelect}/>
          </div>
        );
        break;
      case 4:
        return (
          <div>
            <Results />
          </div>
        )
    }
  }
}

export default App;
```

My `Form` component looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import { RadioGroup, RadioButton } from 'react-radio-buttons';

function Form (props) {
    return (
        <RadioGroup onChange={props.onSelect}>
            {
                props.answers.map(answer => 
                    <RadioButton key={answer.answer} value={answer.archetype}>
                        {answer.answer}
                    </RadioButton>
                )
            }
        </RadioGroup>
    )
}

Form.propTypes = {
  answers: PropTypes.array.isRequired,
  onSelect: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default Form;
```

As of right now, each `Panel` component, as well as the `Results` component are all blank, with the `Panel` components only being containers for different versions of `Form`. The reason I have them as containers is purely so that I can style each panel differently (is this a good idea?).

The behavior I want, as I mentioned, is that when an answer is selected a new component is rendered, based on the change in state. I'm guessing that this isn't happening because `setState()` is asynchronous and changes relying on it won't happen immediately. My question is how do I achieve the behavior I want? Do I use lifecycle methods? I'm still somewhat fuzzy on how those work and how exactly I'd use them in this case. My secondary question (I am still looking for an answer to my first question regardless) is whether or not what I'm doing is good practice at all. If I rendered only different versions of `Form` with updated props, would I be able to style those differently from one another?

Comment: Not sure if it a typo in the question but you are not passing onSelect prop on PanelOne and PanelTwo `onSelect  {this.onSelect}` or maybe is a syntax simplification I didn't know, just make sure onSelect is being called for those

Comment: @diedu That's a typo from when I copied my code over to Stack Overflow. It was always correct in my code, but I'm fixing it now in my question. Thanks for pointing it out!

Comment: There is a lot of code duplication in your question, do you really need 4 different panels to essentially ask a question, offer possible responses and record the returned response? Couldn't your panels be more dynamic? This would make your Panel more dynamic, handling responses could be more dynamic, and your `render` and `onSelect` method would be well, pretty clean. Even your onselect could now use the archetype to increase the state values and the counter, no need for switch statement there

Comment: @Icepickle If I understand your response correctly, I think I'm in agreement. I mentioned in my question that I only have 4 different panels so I can style them differently, and I asked if there was a way for me to render one panel with different props but still style it differently on each render.

Comment: Yeah, these are reusable components, send the style along using the props, as well as the question and the answer

Comment: @Icepickle I'm still a little in the dark on how to re-render my component with its new props after each question is answered. Am I correct in thinking that a lifecycle method is what I'm looking for? Can you point me in the direction of the correct method?

Comment: No, `setState` (or props change) will cause a re-render, I think you need to debug a bit, check if there are any errors in the console. For example, are you sure value is what you expect? You also seem to be missing a comma after `counter` and before `answers` in your initial state, but that could be a copy past failure. Any chance you could create a snippet from your code instead?

Comment: @Icepickle I'm pretty sure... When I run this in my browser and look at my dev tools, my state is changing exactly as I'd predict, i.e. when the selected `value` is 'collaborator', I'm seeing the tally for 'collaborator' increment in my state.

Comment: @bkula I updated my answer a bit with hints for your current implementation ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your current question, things could be written differently, for example your `onSelect` method is now a huge switch statement, although your archetype and state properties seem to match, instead of this huge switch, you could change your statement to something like this:

```
onSelect(value) {
  this.setState(prevState => {
    return {
      [value]: prevState[value] + 1,
      counter: prevState.counter + 1
    }
  });
}
```

This would do the exact same thing, as archetype perfectly matches your properties, and the counter you increase anyhow in every step, no need to do things multiple times ;)

This even goes for your render method as well, no need for a huge switch, just make a dictionary matching state with your panel (in case you wish to do it like that), and you could do this

```
// provided you have a const on top, like
const questionsMap = { 0: 'One', 1: 'Two', 2: 'Three', 3: 'Four' };

render() {
  let { counter, answers } = this.state;
  if (!questionsMap[counter]) {
    // nothing matches, return the results panel
    return (<div>
        <Results />
      </div>);
  }
  let mappedValue = questionsMap['counter'];
  return React.createElement( 'Panel' + mappedValue , { answers: answers['answers' + mappedValue], onSelect: this.onSelect });
}
```

This really reduces a lot of code duplication, and will simplify your cause in the long run, however in the original part of my answer, I also like to give you a different way to structure everything ;)

I mainly want to offer you a different way of structuring your code. Sorry I had to recreate the `RadioButton` & `RadioGroup` new, but I didn't find the correct cdn at once (So ignore those implementations ;) )

Mainly, this application will also give you a small quiz, that can track the correct answers, and which answers were given (however, doesn't track what the correct should have been ;))

You can see that this code is a lot more compact than yours, and uses some es6 features, which really make full use of react & jsx as you can start by using destructuring of the props in the functional components (just a joy to work with) and the usage of `let`, `const` keywords.

I know it doesn't directly answer your question, but I just wanted to show you that you do not need this enormous code duplication, just past styles as props  (or you will have 20+ components for 20+ questions in the future, which is code you never want to maintain)

Jsx & React set high on reusability, if you do think twice, think what you can do to unify your implementation

```js
const RadioGroup = ({ onChange, children = [] }) => {
  return <fieldset>
  { children.map( child => {
    return React.createElement( child.type, {...child.props, key: child.key, onChange } ); }
    ) }
  </fieldset>;
};

const RadioButton = ({ onChange, children, value }) => {
  return <button onClick={(e) => onChange( value )}>{ children }</button>;
};

const Results = ({ correctAnswers, givenAnswers, currentQuestion }) => {
  return <div>
    <div><b>Correct answsers:</b>{ correctAnswers }</div>
    <div><b>Answers given:</b>{ givenAnswers.join(', ') }</div>
    <div><b>False answers:</b>{currentQuestion - correctAnswers}</div>
  </div>
};

const questions = [
  { question: 'Are you on stack overflow?', answers: ['yes', 'no'], correct: 'yes' },
  { question: 'Are you looking for help?', answers: ['yes', 'no'], correct: 'yes' },
  { question: 'Did you find your answer?', answers: ['yes', 'no', 'maybe'], correct: 'maybe' }
];

const Question = ({ question, answers, correct, onSelected }) => {
  return (<div>
    <h2>{ question }</h2>
    <RadioGroup onChange={(e) => onSelected( correct === e, e, correct) }>
    { answers.map( answer => <RadioButton key={answer} value={answer}>{ answer }</RadioButton> ) }
    </RadioGroup>
   </div>);
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(...args) {
    super(...args);
    this.state = {
      currentQuestion: 0,
      correctAnswers: 0,
      givenAnswers: []
    };
  }
  onSelected( wasCorrect, answerGiven, correctAnswer ) {
    this.setState( prevState => ({
      currentQuestion: prevState.currentQuestion + 1,
      correctAnswers: prevState.correctAnswers + (wasCorrect ? 1 : 0),
      givenAnswers: [...prevState.givenAnswers, answerGiven]
    }));
  }
  render() {
    let { currentQuestion } = this.state;
    let { questions } = this.props;
    if (currentQuestion < questions.length) {
      return <div><Question {...questions[currentQuestion]} onSelected={(...args) => this.onSelected(...args)} /></div>;
    }
    return <div><Results {...this.state} /></div>
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( <App questions={questions} />, document.querySelector('#container') );
```

```html
<script id="react" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.6.2/react.js"></script>
<script id="react-dom" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/15.6.2/react-dom.js"></script>
<script id="prop-types" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prop-types/15.6.0/prop-types.js"></script>
<script id="classnames" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/classnames/2.2.5/index.js"></script>
<div id="container"></div>
```

Comment: Really fantastic! Thank you for everything.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who comes across this: I made a really silly mistake and was missing some commas in my `answers` object, in my state. When I fixed this, everything ran correctly.